# Dispute reopen review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I really think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41152644/660921) is not eligible for reopening. But I failed the audit:

[image]

Several reasons that closing this question is legitimate in my opinion:

Points straight from the StackOverflow [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

- Write a title that summarizes the specific problem.

  *"Simulator installs an app by drag-and-drop onto the Simulator window"*

That is more of an observation than a problem or a question.

- Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.

  *"I have tried drag-and-drop onto the Simulator window"*

How did he/she try? OP should share some details in the question with preferably code of this attempt.

- Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.

  *"Does anyone know how this feature is used"*

This is hardly a technical question or issue and if not too broad in the first place it is bound to lead to very extensive answers.

---

I also think a question has to be very good quality to be eligible for reopening. The question closing process is comprehensive (needs 5 close votes) and since the question wasn't edited and/or improved afterwards I would rather prevent reopening a question that busy moderators will end up closing again later.

It is not the first time this happened to me and it is very demotivating to get a reproach of "not paying attention" while I really think this audit is just not representing a good question at all.

I am open for other points of view and maybe I am missing something good in this question here so feel free to shine some light on the good parts of this question that I might be missing.

Comment: You're right. This is a terrible question. And it has received terrible answers. Problem is, lots of people found it useful. Not really sure why.

Comment: Note that the *"Simulator installs an app by drag-and-drop onto the Simulator window"* bit seems to be a quote from the linked change log, its the target of the question. As in -> "What does this bit of the change log mean?".

Comment: Ha! I failed the same audit but on the close queue.

Comment: @Gimby I read it as "this doesn't work, dunno why?"

Comment: There have been proposals for an *"I disagree with this audit"* button. Given the quantity of question here on meta about disputed audits (there is even the tag [tag:disputed-review-audits] for these questions) it would be nice to have such a button available.